# Error on joining voice channel in handshake with discord.py version 0.16.12

Tags: python, websocket, discord.py, handshake

I get the following error when trying to use
`vc = await bot.join_voice_channel(channel)`:

```
  File "bot.py", line 31, in on_ready
    vc = await bot.join_voice_channel(channel)
  File "C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 3211, in join_voice_channel
    yield from voice.connect()
  File "C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 258, in connect
    self.ws = yield from DiscordVoiceWebSocket.from_client(self)
  File "C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 568, in from_client
    timeout=60, loop=client.loop)
  File "C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 358, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\gateway.py", line 65, in _ensure_coroutine_connect
    ws = yield from websockets.connect(gateway, loop=loop, klass=klass)
  File "C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\websockets\py35\client.py", line 19, in __await__
    return (yield from self.client)
  File "C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\websockets\client.py", line 215, in connect
    extra_headers=extra_headers)
  File "C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\websockets\client.py", line 125, in handshake
    raise InvalidStatusCode(status_code)
websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: Status code not 101: 403
```

I was hoping I could avoid upgrading to the new discord.py rewrite version since there are a lot of changes that break my current bot. If anyone has any ideas on why I get this error that would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: Would you please give more information?

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi is there anything specific you would like to know?

Comment: The code of yours!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out voice is no longer supported in 0.16.12, need to upgrade to the rewrite